# JS - create div tags in confined space that can overlap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a little script that will display a div with text in it when triggered (That bit works). When it is triggered these text boxes need to be in the confides of a specific space, a container of sorts.

Here is what I have so far:

```
       <script>
        var socket = io();
        followerName = {};
        player           = {};
        answer       = {};
               var arrAnswers = ["rngesus", "lorgasm", "nintendisco", "samurai", "bigbang"];

        //Socket Setups - These allow me to use functions below
        socket.on('follow', function (followerName) {
                showName(followerName);
                console.log('showdiv');
                //alert('New follower: ' + followerName);
        });
        $(document).ready(function(){
                socket.on('hello', function (answer) {
                        console.log('hello?: ' + answer);
                        var div = document.createElement("div");
                        var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
                        div.setAttribute("id", "fade"+random);
                        div.style.margin = Math.floor((Math.random() * 400) + 1) + "px";
                        div.style.zIndex = Math.floor((Math.random() * 400) + 1);
                        div.style.width = "100px";
                        div.style.height = "100px";
                        div.style.background = "red";
                        div.style.color = "white";
                        div.innerHTML = "Hello";
                        document.body.appendChild(div);
                        $("#fade"+random).delay(3000).fadeOut("slow"); //Fadeout
                });
         });


        //LOCAL FUNCTIONS
        function showName(Name) {
                document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = Name + " just followed.";
        }

</script>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
```

The idea, is that the zIndex will allow text to appear ontop of another and then it will fade out and another div can be created ontop. The divs themselves are made on the fly (They use the random tag to make them unique).

At the moment, they're all being created underneath the previous div that was made. How do I go about making it so they're all in the general area of the container (Which in this case is the body)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the divs after they fade out, they are still taking space after fading out.

```
$("#fade"+random).delay(3000).fadeOut("slow", function() { 
    $(this).remove(); 
});
```

If you need to display them again and can't remove them, you could make the divs absolutely positioned so they are not in the flow of the document.

Comment: It's possible they will stack though as they can be triggered a lot of times

Comment: If you want them to overlap, then make them absolutely positioned as I explained in the answer? "making it so they're all in the general area of the container (Which in this case is the body)" is not a very clear description of how you want it to behave.